# How to Copy File "file1.txt" from local to hadoop with a different name?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I need to copy a file file1.txt from local to hadoop where i want to have "file1.txt" with a different name like "test.txt" in hadoop. Hoow can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try do it like this:

```
hadoop fs -put /path/to/local/file1.txt /path/to/hadoop/text.txt
```

or

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /path/to/local/file1.txt /path/to/hadoop/text.txt
```